# Two variable definition of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a real valued map from the unit interval. Let 
$$A:=\left \{a\in (0,1):\exists    f^*(a)=\lim_{x\ne y,\,(x,y)\to(a,a)} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right \}$$

It is true that if $a\in A$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$. I am trying to show that it is false to claim that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $a\in A$.

Is there any easy example of a function $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfying

1. $f(x)$ is differentiable for every $x \in (0,1)$.
2. There exists $x^* \in (0,1)$ such that $x^* \not \in A$.

so that $A$ is a proper subset of $(0,1)$?

Comment: This definition seems analogous to the definition of derivative inside an interval, i.e. $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$

Comment: @Masacroso If I recall correctly, derivability implies symmetric derivability but the converse does not hold.  If belonging to $A$ was equivalent to having a symmetric derivative, we could show that symmetric derivability implies derivability, which is false (think of $|x|$).

Comment: Differentiability doesnt implies symmetric differentiability, by example the points in the boundary of a compact set are not "symmetric differentiable", this is why I said "inside" some interval. But the definition you have here is not equivalent to symmetric differentiability because $x$ and $y$ can approach $a$ from the same side. I would try some kind of $\epsilon-\delta$ attempt to see what lies here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the existence of $f^*(a)$ is a much stronger condition than the existence of $f'(a)$. For example

**Theorem** If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable then $A$ is the set of points where $f'$ is continuous.

Proof: Suppose that $f'$ is not continuous at $a$. There exists a sequence $x_n\to a$ so that $$f'(x_n)\not\to f'(a).$$ By definition of the derivative there exists $y_n$ with $0<y_n-x_n<1/n$ such that $$\left|f'(x_n)-\frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n}\right|<\frac1n.$$So $(x_n,y_n)\to(a,a)$ but $$\frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n}\not\to f'(a);$$as mentioned in the OP this shows that in fact the limit $f^*(a)$ does not exist.

Suppose now that $f'$ *is* continuous at $a$. Let $\epsilon>0$, and choose $\delta>0$ so that $$|f'(x)-f'(a)|<\epsilon\quad(|x-a|<\delta).$$
Now if $|x-a|<\delta$, $|y-a|<\delta$ and $x\ne y$ then the Mean Value Theorem shows that $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|-f'(a)\right|<\epsilon.$$
So $f^*(a)=f'(a)$. QED

So any differentiable function with a discontinuous derivative is an example of the sort you're looking for.

Comment: I didn't add the $x\neq y$ in the limit because i did not have time to look up how to add a subscript to the arrow, thought it was kind of obvious but your remark is correct, indeed. Cool, I get it. So something like $(x-\frac 12)^2\sin(\frac{1}{x-\frac 12}$ at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ should work? Thank you very much!

Comment: Right. I didn't want to mention the $t^2\sin(1/t)$ thing; like if you didn't know an example of a discontinuous derivative you really shouldn't be working on this problem til you're older, heh. Regarding where to put the "$x\ne y$", I changed your typesetting to something I think is better; feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \sin x$ differentiable everywhere, but $0 \not \in A$. If $0$ were in $A$, then $(x, 0) \to (0,0)$ implies $f^*(0)=1$ but $(x,-x) \to (0,0)$ implies the limit does not exist. If you like, you can shift the function to define on $(0,1)$, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I dont think that $(x,0)\to (0,0)$ is a valid example, constant sequences are prohibited for limits. Maybe Im wrong, just to point. It is not completely clear what means $(x,y)\to (a,a)$ and it definition on terms of sequences.

Comment: You approach the origin via any type of curve. There, I picked two very simple ones to give a contradiction. It has nothing to do with constant sequences or whatever. Take a look at it again.

Comment: Your answer is correct formally, but not really in spirit. The OP's definition of $A$ was simply wrong; by that definition $A$ is always empty, since we can never avoid division by zero. One should instead define $a\in A$ if the limit of $(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)$ exists for $(x,y)\to(a,a)$, _subject to_ $x\ne y$. That makes it an interesting question instead of a trivial silly one..

Comment: To put it another way: You answer is really more of an illustration  of why the question was stated incorrectly than an answer to the "real" question.

Comment: Why you says that for $(x,-x)\to (0,0)$ the limit doesnt exist? I have that $f^*(0)=\lim_{(x,-x)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin (x)-\sin(-x)}{x-(-x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Comment: @Masacroso Yeap, you are right. Wrong choice of function, silly me. $f(x) = x^{4/3}$ will do. Idea is the same.

Comment: Btw, when I said the answer was formally correct I was wrong. I had the impression somehow that you really meant $(x,x)$ instead of $(-x,x)$, and your objection was that the definition of $A$ involves division by zero. Looking at recent comments I see that's not what you meant at all. So just for the record, what you say here is wrong. (You've already agreed it's wrong, but you should note that it's equally wrong with $x^{4/3}$ in place of $\sin(x)$.)